# Machine Learning Algorithms Evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I need to evaluate different machine learning algorithms before choosing the appropriate one to implement in my project. I listed four different algorithms: the k-Nearest Neighbour Algorithm, the Naive Bayes Algorithm, Dynamic Time Warping and Quadratic Discriminant Analysis. I manageed to evaluate the kNN and the Naive Bayes using the Weka toolkit. Do you know of any other tools with which I can evaluate the latter two please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both in R -- [Dynamic Time Warping](http://dtw.r-forge.r-project.org/) and [Quadratic Discriminant Analysis](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/qda.html).

Answer (score 1):

For Python implementation of DTW, you may have a look at

http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/